# displaying xml data via javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, null, undefined

i am building a weather component for an internal website and i am trying to pull the xml data via javascript. However i am having trouble targeting the right node. My code keeps telling me its null or undefined and i cannot seem to figure out the right variable code to target the data.

Here is my code:

```
displayATLWET(0);
function displayATLWET(i) {
    var path = 'http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=33.6413&lon=-84.4501&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml';
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    } else {
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    xmlhttp.open("GET",path,false);
    xmlhttp.send();

    if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
        var xmlDoc;
        var x;
        var temp;
        var xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
        x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data");
        temp = x[1].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

        // tempSUMM = x[1].getElementsByTagName("weather-conditions")[0].getAttribute("weather-summary");

        document.getElementById("atlWet").innerHTML = temp;
    }
}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="atlWet"></div>
```

Comment: what's the expected output?

Comment: it should be a number, like 67, since its calling for temperature. i feel like the issue is the data is nested several layers deep and i am not sure how to retrieve it,

Comment: I get 67. Where are you testing it?

Comment: locally, can you set up a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/rabakimume/edit?js,console

What's the exact node you want to retrieve?

Comment: well..all of them, i had a functioning app, but they restructured their data file and now i have to rebuild the code, but its not working like it has previously,

Comment: so this works great, however when i try to change the console log to a  "document.getElementById("atlWet").innerHTML = tempSUMM;" i get the error message "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"

Comment: @Cornwell any thoughts? thank you.

Comment: Are you including the JS file on the bottom of the page?

Comment: no, it has to be in the header

Comment: Did the code in my answer work for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("atlWet")` is null because the element appears after the script. That is why the script needs to be included in the bottom. If for some reason you cannot put the script in the bottom, call the function after the DOM is loaded, ie:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  displayATLWET(0);
}, false);
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  displayATLWET(0);
}, false);


function displayATLWET(i) {
  var path = 'http://forecast.weather.gov/MapClick.php?lat=33.6413&lon=-84.4501&unit=0&lg=english&FcstType=dwml';
  if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  else
    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");


  xmlhttp.open("GET", path, false);
  xmlhttp.send();


  if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

    var xmlDoc;
    var x;
    var temp;



    xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML;
    x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("data");
    temp = x[i].getElementsByTagName("value")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;

    tempSUMM = x[i].getElementsByTagName("weather-conditions")[0].getAttribute("weather-summary");


    document.getElementById("atlWet").innerHTML = tempSUMM;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="atlWet"></div>
```

Comment: yes! this worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your assistance!! i apologize for the delay in acceptance, i was OOO for the holiday!

Answer (score 0):

You're document.getElementById("atlWet").innerHTML being null means there are no elements with the id atlWet. You should include some of the HTML you're using so we can help.

Comment: the only thing in the html is the div. <div id="atlWet"></div>